# Can't toggle on Enhanced Link Attribution in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm in Property Settings > In-Page Analytics

I'm trying to toggle on "Use enhanced link attribution" but it will not switch on.

The site has UA implemented and has done for some time.

Any other ideas what might be preventing me from switching this on?

Comment: You probably don't have Edit rights at the Property level. I just tested this myself and the "Use enhanced link attribution" toggle is greyed out if I have Collaborate and Read & Analyze only. You can even have Manage users permission, but without Edit, you won't be able to toggle that switch.

Comment: That was it - thank you.